# Make wal2json listen to tables without Primary Key

Tags: postgresql, apache-kafka, debezium, wal

When I create a table with a **Primary Key** on PostgreSQL 10

```
create table test (t1 int, t2 varchar, primary key(id));
```

and stream data from PostgreSQL to Kafka through Debezium using wal2json with these SQL

```
insert into test values (1, 'Test1');
update test set t2='Test2' where t1=1;
delete from test where t1=1;
```

I get these `JSON` from kafka Consumer:

Insert (**C**reate)

```
{
  "before": null,
  "after": {
    "t1": 1,
    "t2": "Test1"
  ...
}
```

**U**pdate

```
{
  "before": {
    "t1": 1,
    "t2": null
  },
  "after": {
    "t1": 1,
    "t2": "Test2"
  ...
}
```

**D**elete

```
{
  "before": {
    "t1": 1,
    "t2": null
  },
  "after": null,
  ...
}
```

But when I create the table without a **Primary Key**

```
create table test (t1 int, t2 varchar);
```

and stream data from PostgreSQL to Kafka, I get `JSON` for `insert` only, not for `update` and `delete`

```
{
  "before": null,
  "after": {
    "t1": 1,
    "t2": "Test1"
  ...
}
```

---

I've read this [documentation](https://debezium.io/docs/connectors/postgresql/) which states that

> wal2json plug-in does not emit events for tables without primary keys

Thus, is there **any** workaround to use CDC on tables without **Primary Key** to also get `update` and `delete` as well? *(As almost all tables were already created without **Primary Key**)*

Answer (score 0):

do you depend on `wal2json`? If not and you use PostgreSQL 10 and higher you might give a try to a new `pgoutput` decoder that is available OOTB. It might resolve your problem.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but we depend on wal2json :(

Answer (score 0):

It is feasible.

Using the following sql:

```
ALTER TABLE "<schema>"."<table>" REPLICA IDENTITY FULL;
```

after executing abot sql, all columns of tables without primary key will be included in the wal2json output.

demo outpout of wal2json:

```
{
    "change": [
        {
            "kind": "update",
            "schema": "public",
            "table": "test4_no_pk",
            "columnnames": [
                "id",
                "value"
            ],
            "columntypes": [
                "integer",
                "character varying(100)"
            ],
            "columnvalues": [
                3,
                "hello2-1"
            ],
            "oldkeys": {
                "keynames": [
                    "id",
                    "value"
                ],
                "keytypes": [
                    "integer",
                    "character varying(100)"
                ],
                "keyvalues": [
                    3,
                    "hello2"
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

See [REPLICA IDENTITY] of [PostgreSQL: Documentation: 9.4: ALTER TABLE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/sql-altertable.html) for details.